# php preg_replace regex with ? and &

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm really trying to figure out how to write a preg_replace for this string...

```
/url/?12345678910&stackoverflow=rocks
```

...which I want to become...

```
/url/?_uniqueId_&stackoverflow=rocks
```

The string contains more ?s and &s, however this is the first occurance of the characters in the string.

I've tried the following, but it doesn't even give me a response:

```
preg_replace("/\/url\/\?[^)]+\&/","_uniqueId_",$link);
```

Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Why don't you use [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you assign the results of `preg_replace` to a variable?

```
$link = '/url/?12345678910&stackoverflow=rocks';
$res = preg_replace("/\/url\/\?[^)]+\&/","/url/?_uniqueId_&",$link);
echo $res;
```

Also, I added the other parts from the replaced string you missed. The regex could otherwise be changed to:

```
$res = preg_replace("~/url/\?[^&]+&~","/url/?_uniqueId_&",$link);
```

Which should be a bit faster, and I used different delimiters to avoid excessive escaping. Also `&` doesn't need to be escaped.

Or use lookarounds:

```
$res = preg_replace("~(?<=/url/\?)[^&]+(?=&)~","_uniqueId_",$link);
```

Comment: Thanks! Your first example "kinda" works - it replaces from the first ? to the very last &, which destroys the entire link unfortunately. The other two examples I can't get to work at all. Any ideas about the first one, however?

Comment: @MadMarvin Strange... You could change the first one to `/\/url\/\?[^)]+?\&/` to make it work better though.

Comment: @MadMarvin Oh, I forgot to remove the `/` from the regex. Both of the 2 last regex should work now.